# How can I use the classes from a jar file in another files, different directory?

Tags: java, class, jar, package, classpath

Im new to Java and I wanted to use the classes from a jar file, that I've created, in a Main class outside, but when I try to compile from the terminal It doesnt find these classes. I dont know if im writing wrong the import statement, or im setting wrong the classpaths.

The jar file full address : 
`/home/cristian/Escritorio/The\ complete\ Java\ developer\ course/Sección\ 11/Packages/ThejarFile/example/game/myJarFile.jar`

The Main class full address : 
`/home/cristian/Escritorio/The\ complete\ Java\ developer\ course/Sección\ 11/Packages/com/cristian/example/Main.java`

This is the Main class where I want to use these classes:

```
    package com.cristian.example;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.List;


    import ThejarFile.example.game.Player;
    import ThejarFile.example.game.Monster;
    import ThejarFile.example.game.ISaveable;

    public class Main { 
....
```

I've tried this:

```
 ~/Escritorio/The complete Java developer course/Sección 11/Packages$ javac -cp .:ThejarFile/example/game/myJarFile.jar com/cristian/example/Main.java
```

And this :

```
~/Escritorio/The complete Java developer course/Sección 11/Packages$ javac -cp .:/home/cristian/Escritorio/The\ complete\ Java\ developer\ course/Sección\ 11/Packages/ThejarFile/example/game/myJarFile.jar com/cristian/example/Main.java
```

Answer (score 0):

The **javac** is for compiling and when compiling you refer to the file path with "/"(Windows) or "\"(Unix-Based) and the .java file suffix:

- javac com/cristian/example/Main.java

The **java** is for executing an already compiled class. You refer to the .class compiled file, using the "." without the suffix .class file:

- java -cp .:ThejarFile/example/game/myJarFile.jar com.cristian.example.Main